# vimdiff in cygwin is not working properly

Tags: vim, cygwin, vimdiff

When I was comparing two files with vimdiff in my cygwin,

```
vimdiff a.c b.c
```

all lines were folded (as below)

[image: all-folded]

Then I used `zR` to open all folders, but no difference was showed.

[image: no-difference]

Another weird thing here is, when I start to add a new line (by BUTTON o), it start to show difference:
[image: new-difference]

I found that my `vimdiff` is actually linking to `gvim`, no sure if this is the problem?

```
$ type diff
diff is /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim72/diff

$ type vimdiff
vimdiff is /usr/bin/vimdiff

$ ll /usr/bin/vimdiff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dhuang7 Domain Users 25 Jul 27 16:35 /usr/bin/vimdiff -> /etc/alternatives/vimdiff

$ ll /etc/alternatives/vimdiff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dhuang7 Domain Users 17 Jul 27 16:35 /etc/alternatives/vimdiff -> /usr/bin/gvim.exe

$ ll /usr/bin/gvim.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dhuang7 Domain Users 1801245 Jun 28 12:39 /usr/bin/gvim.exe
```

Btw there is no `.vimrc` when this was running. And I had tried to add `set diffopt=filler,context:50` in to my `.vimrc` but still the same.

Tried `:messages` after vimdiff starting but no error was seen:

```
"a.c" 7L, 74C
"b.c" 6L, 59C
```

Comment: There's a bug somewhere. Diffing those two files works as expected here.

Comment: Do any errors show up when you type ":messages" after starting vimdiff?  My guess is that you are missing a _diff_ binary, or it isn't in your $PATH.

Comment: @Heptite No error was seen with `:messages`, I had updated my question with the output.

Comment: What does "type diff" output?

Comment: @Heptite "type diff" shows /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim72/diff. Had updated my question again, thanks for asking.

Comment: That is not a Cygwin executable, it's a "native" Windows executable.  I don't know if this would cause problems for a Cygwin Vim/gVim executable, but it might. I suggest running the Cygwin setup/installer executable, searching for "diff" and installing it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the exact same issue. I noticed the following error after executing :diffupdate

```
/bin/bash: /usr/share/vim/vim73diff: No such file or directory
```

That file obviously does not exist so I suspect that @Heptite was correct in saying that vi cannot find a diff binary. diff.exe was already in my PATH though so I'm confused by this. However, symlinking it seems to fix the problem.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/diff /usr/share/vim/vim73diff
```

Ugly, but I'm back working again.

Comment: `:diffupdate` returns `E97: Cannot create diffs` in my vimdiff. Not sure why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and running `:diffupdate` returned `E97: Cannot create diffs`

Solution: my `/tmp` partition was full. The `diff` command run internally by vim was not able to store the result. Just cleaned this up and everything was working again.